# Can't get PyQt5 to display an animated gif

Tags: python, pyqt5

It was working earlier with layouts, but I can't make it work without, the gif is not showing up.

```
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie

scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
gifFile = (scriptDir + os.path.sep + '78.gif')

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.MovieLabel = QLabel(self)
        self.movie = QMovie(gifFile)
        self.MovieLabel.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()

window = MainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is the window displayed? Does gifFile exist? If both are yes answers then run your script in the console: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS = 1 python /path/of/script.py` and share the log.

Comment: Yes, the window is displayed and the gif file also exists (same folder as the script). Unfortunately I couldn't run the debug: The term 'QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: You have to use the console of your OS or CMD if you are on windows, do not use the console of your IDE

Comment: I did, but I get the same error.

Comment: The error may be the same, I am interested in the log to be able to analyze the cause of the error.

Comment: No I mean I still can't run it from the command prompt as I get the same error as before  'QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS' is not recognized.....

Comment: Mmm so weird. Add `import os` `os.environ["QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS"] = "1"` before  `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` and execute `python /path/of/script.py`

Comment: okay, I'm confused. After trying irahorecka's working code, I've removed the resize and geometry lines to try it with os.environ["QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS"] = "1" and now it is working. Also removing QApplication(sys.argv) now throws an error, while it it didn't do that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working rendition of your code. The biggest factor is make sure your `QLabel` geometry is large enough to accommodate your gif (this also applies for `MainWindow`):

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie

scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
gifFile = (scriptDir + os.path.sep + '78.gif')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Resize main window to be 600px / 400px
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.MovieLabel = QLabel(self)
        # Set gif content to be same size as window (600px / 400px)
        self.MovieLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 600, 400))
        self.movie = QMovie(gifFile)
        self.MovieLabel.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I get "NameError: name 'QMainWindow' is not defined" using this.

Comment: Did you run the entire code block I posted? I noticed your code block is missing the `QMainWindow` import.

Comment: You are right, I did miss that, it is indeed working with resize.

Comment: Awesome - if you found the answer helpful, could you mark it as the accepted answer?